# Project B inside Project A's subfolder - committing local changes to Project B remote

Tags: git, dvcs

Let say I'm owner of two remote projects: `MainProject` and `AppsProject`.

In local repository I want to have `AppsProject` in `MainProject`'s subdirectory (`apps/`).

I've tried to use `subtree merge` strategy (ref.: [Pro Git Book](http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html))
In `MainProject`'s directory. I've done that:

```
$ git remote add apps-remote git@bitbucket.com:me/apps.git
$ git checkout -b apps-branch apps-remote/master
$ git checkout master
$ git read-tree --prefix=apps/ -u apps-branch
$ git checkout apps-branch
$ git pull
```

Actually what I want now is to be able commit local `apps/` changes to `AppsProject` remote repository and anything what is not in `apps/` to `MainProject` remote repository.

How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a submodule:

```
$ cd MainProject
$ git submodule add git@bitbucket.com:me/apps.git apps
$ git commit -a -m "added a submodule"
$ git push
```

Now to clone brand new:

```
$ git clone --recursive git@bitbucket.com:me/MainProject.git
```

Or if you had it cloned somewhere already but before you added the submodule:

```
$ git submodule update --init 
#Or without the --init to update the submodule
```

Keep in mind that when you make changes to the submodule, you first want to commit the changes in the submodule, and then commit the changes in the main repo so that it picks it up. The submodule is always frozen at the last commit in the main repo.

Comment: I add and commit in apps/ directory? How to push to AppsProject remote?

Comment: Its referencing the remote repo. Make changes, commit and push.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the inner project a submodule. This would allow you to treat the outer project separately from it.